# Undisclose recipients php without any extensions only mail() function

Tags: php, email

I am trying to not disclose the recipients when I send an email but I am failing on this:

```
$email = implode('; ', $email); // array where I have the emails
$to = $email; // webmaster@domain.com; webmaster@anotherdomain.com
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers  = "From: noreply@domainfromwhereisendemail.com\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "To: Undisclosed Recipients <noreply@domainfromwhereisendemail.com>\r\n";
//$headers .= "Cc: $to\r\n";
$message = 
<<<START
This is the message
START;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I tried adding Cc or Bcc, but not working, it is adding besides the emails Undisclosed recipients. I am trying to do this without any other extensions, I checked a lot of questions from stackoverflow here but did not accomplish this. Emails are still being shown to each.

Comment: You may send the email to yourself or to a generic email, and add BCC for each recipient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nope** you can't stop that from nondisclosure, unless you send the emails separately using a loop.

```
$email = implode('; ', $email); // <---- Don't do this.
```

#### The loop up way..

```
foreach($email as $mail)   #<---- Use a foreach and loop through
{
$to = $mail;
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers  = "From: noreply@domainfromwhereisendemail.com\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message =
    <<<START
    This is the message
START;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Ohh, could you please give me an example based on mine, will much appreciate.

Comment: It's working, I also needed to // comment $headers .= "To: Undisclosed Recipients... Will mark as accepted as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: Well, you should remove the **To:** part from the header. While, the approach would generally work, it *might* be a problem, because it'd send the emails one by one - the script would eventually timeout. Setting the **From:** header is always a terrible idea - do not do that. Look at the **ôkio** comment and follow that instead.

Comment: @blue hmm Don't wish to timeout, I am trying to understand, how exactly do you send the email like okio said, do I need to add bcc instead of the line I have cc?

Comment: @user3467855, Both are same , even you can use this above recommended approach , because on both cases you are going to send the mails to each recipients separetely.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - I'm afraid you're slightly wrong. Take a look at my answer for a hint to the single call version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **ôkio** solution with a **single** call to `mail()`:

```
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers = "X-Mailer: php\r\n";
# $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; # do you really need that?
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
foreach($email as $mail){
    $headers .= "Bcc: ".$mail."\r\n";
}
$message =
    <<<START
    This is the message
START;
mail('non@existing.email', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: When there are 150 emails and if you are looking to send emails for first 10 users , How will you change the logic for this ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - that's a totally different issue, that is extremely easily resolved by filtering the values from **$email** array in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe correct , but when you use the **bcc** feature, the recipient can easily find out that the mail was not exclusively sent for him/her instead to a group (However, the other recipients email will not be disclosed). If the OP does not care abt this issue , then this is the right way to do.